# Non-conformable arrays | Error calculating T squared | R

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

I am trying to calculate T squared. I have the following parameters:

```
> invS #inverse variance covariance matrix          
          x1        x2
x1  0.005536320 -0.001167908
x2 -0.001167908  0.002635186

> n # number of rows
[1] 11

> d_mean
   x1        x2 
-9.363636 13.272727
```

When I am trying to calculate the T squared:

```
> Tsq <- n* d_mean*invS*t(d_mean)
```

...I get this error:

```
Error in n* d_mean*invS*t(d_mean) : non-conformable arrays
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think what you want is `n * d_mean %*% invS %*% t(d_mean)`. `%*%` is the matrix product, `*` the element-wise product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Tsq <- n * d_mean %*% invS %*% t(d_mean).
```

`%*%` is the matrix product and `*` the element-wise product.